# why isn't this if statement working in my query?

Tags: php, sql, sequelpro

I am querying the database, and the query I wrote isn't working. I have researched using google, but made no progress. Help please!

```
${$name} = array();
    ${$name} = $db->query('SELECT', "
    SELECT
    SUM(IF(`date`=‘2014-01’, `value`, 0.00)) as `Jan_2014`,
    SUM(IF(`date`=‘2014-02’, `value`, 0.00)) as `Feb_2014,
    SUM(IF(`date`=‘2014-03’, `value`, 0.00)) as `Mar_2014`,
    SUM(IF(`date`=‘2014-04’, `value`, 0.00)) as `Apr_2014`,
    SUM(IF(`date`=‘2014-05’, `value`, 0.00)) as `May_2014`,
    SUM(IF(`date`=‘2014-06’, `value`, 0.00)) as `Jun_2014`
    FROM reporting.$name a
    INNER JOIN
    reporting.Locations b
    ON
    a.store_name=b.city
    $where
    ", 'array');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I got an error that states...

> SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '��2014-01’, `value`, 0.00)) as `Jan_2014`, SUM(IF(`date`=‘2014' at line

Comment: a backtick also looks missing here `Feb_2014,`

Comment: just noticed the backtick missing!

Comment: ok stackoverflow is really starting to piss me off. I copied and pasted my code from my ide and now looking at it, the code in the codeblock changed when i pasted it. there was a backtick missing, my fault there, but it changed some of my backticks to single quotes, and now i am getting answers that aren't the least bit helpful. and people are downvoting my question. the code I copied looks like this(i am checking this line by line after pasting this time) @arms

Comment: ${$name} = array();
  ${$name} = $db->query('SELECT', "
  SELECT
  SUM(IF(`date`=`2014-01`, `value`, 0.00)) as `Jan_2014`,
  SUM(IF(`date`=`2014-02`, `value`, 0.00)) as `Feb_2014`,
  SUM(IF(`date`=`2014-03`, `value`, 0.00)) as `Mar_2014`,
  SUM(IF(`date`=`2014-04`, `value`, 0.00)) as `Apr_2014`,
  SUM(IF(`date`=`2014-05`, `value`, 0.00)) as `May_2014`,
  SUM(IF(`date`=`2014-06`, `value`, 0.00)) as `Jun_2014`
  FROM reporting.$name a
  INNER JOIN
  reporting.Locations b
  ON
  a.store_name=b.city
  $where
  ", 'array');
 } catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
 }

Answer (score 1):

Don't use those curly quotes around the year, use backticks instead.

Comment: i did use backticks. when i pasted this into the codeblock it changed it on here and i didn't notice. i am frustrated by this. twice i have copied and pasted my code and it not be the same as what i pasted into the codeblock. and i am getting my questions downvoted because of it. what gives?

Answer (score 1):

Change the quotation characters from ‘ to '

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with `'` symbols you are using.

```
${$name} = array();
    ${$name} = $db->query('SELECT', "
    SELECT
        SUM(IF('date'='2014-01', 'value', 0.00)) as 'Jan_2014',
        SUM(IF('date'='2014-02', 'value', 0.00)) as 'Feb_2014',
        SUM(IF('date'='2014-03', 'value', 0.00)) as 'Mar_2014',
        SUM(IF('date'='2014-04', 'value', 0.00)) as 'Apr_2014',
        SUM(IF('date'='2014-05', 'value', 0.00)) as 'May_2014',
        SUM(IF('date'='2014-06', 'value', 0.00)) as 'Jun_2014'
        FROM reporting.$name a
        INNER JOIN
        reporting.Locations b
        ON
        a.store_name=b.city
        $where
        ", 'array');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```